# sheet gives me null pointer apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls

I want to create a file .xls but when I set a  value it gives me null pointer. this is my code  :

(the file xls is empty at start and I need to create two sheet from the code):

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
       Sheet general=wb.createSheet("General"); 
    
    //after this line it gives me null point
                Row row = general.getRow(0);    
                Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
```

It seems that "general" is null.Anyone can help me?

Comment: You probably blame the wrong code line. I suspect it is `row.getCell(1)` which throws `NPE` because `row` is null. A new created empty sheet does not contain any rows. Those need to be created first using [Sheet.createRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createRow-int-). Same for the cells then. See [Row.createCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#createCell-int-). Always good to read: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getRow(0)` throws Exception because row-0 does not exist.
you need to create the row in the first place :

```
Row row = general.createRow(0);
```

Comment: [Sheet.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-) will not throw exception. It returns `null` if the row does not exist. So `row` is `null` then and `row.getCell` throws `NPE`.

Answer (score 0):

Row row = general.getRow(0) will give you null as the row doesn't exist. Only once it is created using general.createRow(0), it can be used. So once rwo at 0 is created, if you call getRow(0), it will return that row. And only a non-null row can have a cell.

You can create your own util method like below which can be used to get the row if not created.

```
public Row getRow(Sheet sheet, int rowNo)
{
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNo);
    if(row == null)
    {
        row = sheet.createRow(rowNo);
    }
    return row;
}
```

row.getCell would also face similar problem. It should create cell first. Or you can use this.

```
Cell cell = row.getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
```

Comment: There is [CellUtil](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html) which has those utility methods already.

Comment: Oh, great. Thanks for the info. :).